# How could I add significant amount of latex on graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I generate the image below easily?

I'm particulary interested in scaling brackets given graph nodes.

Is this easy to do in graphviz and then somehow put latex over it, or is this image completely hand drawn?

The image below does have selectable text on nodes and around brackets when it is in the pdf.

[image: Graphviz generated image with graph tree having brackets and latex]

Comment: Adding a significant amount of LaTeX to the image is also feasible: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MVTZ5.png

Comment: true that! :D haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a TikZ `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,decorations.pathreplacing,matrix,positioning}
\colorlet{lightblue}{blue!60!white}
\colorlet{darkgreen}{green!60!black}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >={Triangle[]},
  font=\ttfamily,
  b/.style = {lightblue,fill=lightblue!40},
  g/.style = {darkgreen,fill=darkgreen!40}
  ]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,column sep=.5cm,row sep=.1cm,
  nodes={
    lightgray,draw,thick,fill=lightgray!40,circle,
    minimum size=3ex,inner sep=1pt,anchor=south
  }] (m) {
          &       &       &       &     {}&     {}\\
          &       &       &       &     {}&     {}\\
          &     {}&     {}&|[g]|{}&|[g]|{}&|[g]|E \\
          &       &       &       &     {}&     {}\\
   |[b]|S &|[b]|{}&|[b]|R &|[b]|{}&|[b]|{}&|[b]|E \\
          &       &       &       &     {}&     {}\\
          &     {}&     {}&|[g]|{}&|[g]|E &       \\
          &       &       &       &     {}&       \\
          &       &       &       &     {}&       \\
  };
  % Black arrows
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 4)] in {5,6}
    \draw[->] (m-3-\lasti.east) to (m-3-\i.west);
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 1)] in {2,...,6}
    \draw[->] (m-5-\lasti.east) to (m-5-\i.west);
  \draw[->] (m-7-4.east) to (m-7-5.west);
  % Green arrows
  \draw[darkgreen,->] (m-5-3.east) to[bend left] (m-3-4.west);
  \draw[darkgreen,->] (m-5-3.east) to[bend right] (m-7-4.west);
  % Gray arrows
  \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {1,2} {
    \foreach \row/\bend in {3/left, 7/right}
      \draw[lightgray,->] (m-5-\i.east) to[bend \bend]  (m-\row-\j.west);
  }
  \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {4,5} {
    \foreach \row/\bend in {1/left, 2/left}
      \draw[lightgray,->] (m-3-\i.east) to[bend \bend]  (m-\row-\j.west);
  }
  \foreach \i[evaluate=\i as \j using int(\i+1)] in {4,5} {
    \foreach \row/\bend in {4/left, 6/right}
      \draw[lightgray,->] (m-5-\i.east) to[bend \bend]  (m-\row-\j.west);
  }
  \foreach \row/\bend in {8/right, 9/right}
    \draw[lightgray,->] (m-7-4.east) to[bend \bend]  (m-\row-5.west);
  % Loss
  \node[right=0pt of m-3-6] {loss=0};
  \node[right=0pt of m-5-6] {loss=.2};
  \node[right=0pt of m-7-5] {loss=.8};
  % Braces
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},lightblue,thick]
    (m-7-3 |- m-7-3.south) -- node[below=10pt] (rollin) {rollin} (m-5-1 |- m-7-3.south);
  \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=10pt},lightblue,thick]
    (m-5-6 |- m-9-5.south) -- node[below=10pt] (rollout) {rollout} (m-5-4 |- m-9-5.south);
  \path (rollin) -- node[lightblue,align=right,rotate=90] {one-step \\ deviations} (rollout);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]